# numerical analysis-biection method

Tags: numerical-methods

I have to write a program that implements the bisection method.The program should end if the number of iterations  surpass the maximum number of iterations,or if one or both of these conditions :
$\left |  x_{k}-x_{k-1} \right | $ < ε  and $ \left |  f(x_{k}) \right | $< ε
are valid??
Which should be my termination criteria when the first interval is [a,b]...Could it be |b-a|<ε?? If yes,why???

Answer (score 0):

Remember that $x_k$ stand for your iterates. If you were to check the conditions $\big|x_k-x_{k-1}\big|$ when you start your program, you will need to know what $x_0$ and $x_1$ are. Usually, $x_0= \frac{b+a}{2}$ if $f(a)\times f(b) < 0$. To compute $x_1$, you will need to apply the bisection method to the new interval $[a, \frac{b+a}{2}]$ or $[\frac{b+a}{2}, b]$ (depending on what $f(b)$ and $f(a)$).

So to answer your question, the first stopping criteria would not be $|b-a|< \epsilon$ because $x_0\neq a$ and $x_1\neq b$ (not necessarily).

Comment: Could you give me an example?If for example the maximum number of iterations is 100,ε is 0.001
and the initial interval is [a,b] =[0,2]

what is equal to first

$\big|x_k-x_{k-1}\big|$ that we use????

Comment: You will need to know what your function $f(x)$ is. The iterates $x_0,x_1, \dots$ are determined by your function. So say for example your function is $f(x)=x-2/3$ (clearly, we know that the solution is $2/3$).

Comment: You will need to know what your function $f(x)$ is. The iterates $x_0,x_1, \dots$ are determined by your function. So say for example your function is $f(x)=x-2/3$ (clearly, we know that the solution is $2/3$).

You check that $f(0) <0$ and $f(2)>0$, and so $x_0=(2+0)/2=1$. Since $f(1)<0$, your new interval becomes $[1, 2]$. 

You will again that $f(1)<0$ and $f(2)>0$ and so your $x_1=(1+2)/2=3/2$. Since $f(3/2)>0$, your new interval will be $[1, 3/2]$. 

Notice that after the first two iterations, you have $x_0$ and $x_1$, you can use that to start checking for your stopping criteria.